# Leer dos números en python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en python sobre una combinatoria. El juez online cuando envío el código me marca error, y es por la entrada:

La entrada es:

```
5 3
```

salida es

```
10
```

Pero python no me deja hacer esa entrada de datos horizontalmente, lo que me deja hacer es:

```
5 
3
```

Es decir, de forma vertical.

[enlace al planteamiento del problema](https://sites.google.com/view/ejerciciocombinatoria/p%C3%A1gina-principal)

```py
def factorial(numero):
    if(numero == 0 or numero == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return numero * factorial(numero-1)

caso = int(input())
while caso>0:
    n=long(input()) 
    m=long(input())
    print(factorial(n)/((factorial(m))*(factorial(n-m))))
    caso-=1
```

Comment: No se puede ver el planteamiento del ejercicio, se requiere iniciar sesión. Deberías colocarlo en otro sitio mas libre para poder verlo mas fácilmente el enunciado.

Comment: En python2 `input()` intenta convertir lo que ha leido a entero, y eso fallará si no es un entero, sino una cadena como es el caso en que contenga varios números separados por espacios. Debes usar `raw_input()` para leer esa entrada como cadena, y una vez la tengas leida puedes usar `split()` para separarla por los espacios, y usar `int()` sobre cada trozo resultante.

Answer (score 1):

¿Tal vez algo como lo siguiente puede funcionar? Leer el input como cadena y utilizar `split` para convertirlo en dos partes, y después convertir cada parte en `integer`.

```py
while caso>0:
    cadena_input = raw_input()
    n, m = cadena_input.split()
    n = long(n)
    m = long(m)
```

Por cierto, para calcular la solución con números más grandes, seria interesante escribirlo como `n*(n-1)* ... *(n-m+1) / (1*2*...*m)`.

En código, con un test para ahorrar tiempo cuando `m` es más grande que `n/2` y haciendo las divisiones paso a paso:

```
def comb(n, m):
    if m > n/2:
        m = n - m
    res = 1
    for i in range(1, m+1):
        res *= (n - i + 1) / i
    return res
```

Comment: ¿Ha sido útil la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Con [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#input) puedes leer una cadena de texto. Con [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) puedes dividir una cadena, y luego con [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#int) puedes convertir cada elemento de la cadena dividida en un número:

```py
entrada = input()
lista = entrada.split(' ')
num1 = int(lista[0])
num2 = int(lista[1])

print(num1)
print(num2)
```

Comment: Hola @Roger. Una respuesta que solo lleva código no es suficiente. Debes explicar lo que hace. No olvides leer [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esta respuesta no funcionará con python2, que era un requisito en la pregunta. En python2 debe usarse `raw_input()` para obtener una cadena (que es lo que en python3 se hace simplemente con `input()` y lo que tu programa está asumiendo). Pero si lo corriges, tu respuesta no sería diferente de la que ya estaba dada hace un año

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con este código:

```
number_a, number_b = map(int, input().split())
```